# How to get embed_url link for Facebook live video C#

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

I'm using [Facebook SDK](https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/facebook-csharp-sdk) in C# to create a live video in Facebook page using below code

```
var client = new FacebookClient(access_token);
Dictionary<string, object> parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
parameters.Add("status", "LIVE_NOW");
parameters.Add("description", "some sample description about video");
var result = (JsonObject)client.Post("page_id/live_videos", parameters);
```

`result` is JsonObject, it has only 3 key-value pairs  [`stream-url, secure_stream_url and id`]
I'm not getting [`embed_html`] in returned JsonObject.

Whereas if I do the same using graph api explorer, I get 5 key-value pair as response. [`status, stream-url, secure_stream_url, embed_html, and id`
]

I don't need `status` as I manually mention it while sending POST request but how can I get `embed_html` link via C#?

Comment: Are you using the same API version when testing in GAE? Documentation doesn’t mention that you should get `embed_html` returned. But you got the video id, so you can easily go look up that value using an extra API request.

Comment: @CBroe, Thanks for your reply. Using video `id`, i'm able to get `emded_html` url via GET request.